# AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'row_len'

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I'm trying to run [this](http://codepad.org/LwgZco0K) script and get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nimeKoostaja.py", line 19, in <module>
    wb = copy(book)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils/copy.py", line 13, in copy
    w
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils/filter.py", line 827, in process
    reader(chain[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils/filter.py", line 66, in __call__
    for col_x in xrange(sheet.row_len(row_x)):
AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'row_len'
```

I'm using xubuntu 12.10. Interesting is, that same code in windows 7 and this thing doesn't happen. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: What xlutils version is installed? I'm on ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7, xlutils 1.5.2 and don't have AttributeError while xlutils.copy.copy(book).

Comment: I'm using xlutils 1.5.2.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev the xlsutils version is not so relevant. The `Sheet` object is provided by `xlrd`. Of course an old version of `xlutils` might not use the `row_len`, but this version does not seem to support older `xlrd` versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you are running an old version of `xlrd` as that is what provides the sheet. 
What version of xlrd are you using on xubunut? (or is that *xubuntu*)

Using this test program:

```
import os
import xlrd
print 'xlrd:   ', xlrd.__VERSION__
import xlwt
print 'xlwt:   ', xlwt.__VERSION__
import xlutils.copy
print 'xlutils:', open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
    xlutils.copy.__file__), 'version.txt')).read()


from xlrd import open_workbook, cellname, XL_CELL_TEXT
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

# open fail
book = open_workbook('name.xls')
# make copy
wb = copy(book)

print 'finished'
```

And different versions of xlrd, I get the following outputs:

```
2013-03-14 18:33:30.201494 ['python2.7', 'test.py']
xlrd:    0.9.0
xlwt:    0.7.4
xlutils: 1.5.2

finished
```

and

```
2013-03-14 18:35:40.241518 ['python2.7', 'test.py']
xlrd:    0.7.3
xlwt:    0.7.4
xlutils: 1.5.2

finished
```

and

```
2013-03-14 18:42:06.703188 ['python2.7', 'test.py']
xlrd:    0.6.1
xlwt:    0.7.4
xlutils: 1.5.2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    wb = copy(book)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils/copy.py", line 13, in copy
    w
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils/filter.py", line 827, in process
    reader(chain[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils/filter.py", line 66, in __call__
    for col_x in xrange(sheet.row_len(row_x)):
AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'row_len'
```

Comment: That was the case. I installed xlrd with `apt-get install python-xlrd`. It installs quite an old version. Uninstalled it and downloaded [xlrd 0.9.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and problem solved.

Comment: this answer keeps on giving :)